# JS-generated SVG doesn't fill space

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, size

I have a SVG generated with JS and D3, located inside a table cell. The problem is that the space filled by the SVG seems to be ignored, just like if it was outside the table: When I add another row, it locates over the SVG.
The link of the page is [here](http://visualinfoglobal.com/Versio2/Cat/Poblacio/Actual/)

Does anyone know how to solve this??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `position: absolute` on the div id="mapCont". Kill that and it behaves as expected.

In the future try to create a [mcve] and post all the code here.